# Pandas Concatenate DataFrames, Keep One Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames:

```
>>> df1
              above below
asn   country
12345 US      5     4
      MX      6     3
54321 MX      4     5
>>> df2
              above below
asn   country
12345 MX      1     0
54321 MX      0     1
      US      1     0
```

Note that while there are some common indexes (`12345/MX` and `54321/MX`) there are some indexes that only appear in `df1` (`12345/US`) and some that only appear in `df2` (`54321/US`)

I wish to add the values together so that if a row does not exist in `df1`, it is added, and if a row does not exist in `df2`, the counts are unaffected.

Desired output:

```
>>> (df1 + df2, somehow)
12345 US      5     4
      MX      7     3
54321 MX      4     6
      US      1     0
```

What's happening to me:

```
>>> df1 + df2
12345 US      NaN   NaN
      MX      7.0   3.0
54321 MX      4.0   6.0
      US      NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `add` with `fill_value` parameter:

```
df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
               above  below
asn   country              
12345 MX         7.0    3.0
      US         5.0    4.0
54321 MX         4.0    6.0
      US         1.0    0.0
```

And, you can `astype` to get back to integers:

```
df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
               above  below
asn   country              
12345 MX           7      3
      US           5      4
54321 MX           4      6
      US           1      0
```

Comment: Would you know an easy way to extend this so that any columns present in `df1` which are not present in `df1` are ignored? The script where I'm using this, `df1` is a counter stored to disk and `df2` is computed each time the script runs. However `df2` has a lot of other columns which are ultimately used to determine whether `above` or `below` gets set to 1

Comment: @stevendesu  `df2.add(df1).dropna()`  Does that work?

Comment: Without the `fill_value=0` some of the `above` and `below` counts fail to get added up correctly, and with the entirety of the extra columns showing `NaN` the `.dropna()` function is dropping every row -- so `df2.add(df1).dropna()` returns an empty DataFrame

Comment: I tried `df1.add(df2).dropna(axis=1, how="all")` and this at least returned the proper number of rows and proper columns, but some of the rows showed `NaN` instead of adding properly.

Comment: Can you post want your expected output is as a mod this question? Or better yet post a new question with your expected out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039402/pandas-dataframe-add-ignore-missing-columns