# Pandas DataFrame.add() -- ignore missing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two DataFrames:

```
>>> history
              above below
asn   country
12345 US          5     4
      MX          6     3
54321 MX          4     5
>>> current
              above below
asn   country
12345 MX          1     0
54321 MX          0     1
      US          1     0
```

I keep a running count of the "above" and "below" values in the `history` DataFrame like so:

```
>>> history = history.add(current, fill_value=0)
>>> history
               above  below
asn   country              
12345 MX         7.0    3.0
      US         5.0    4.0
54321 MX         4.0    6.0
      US         1.0    0.0
```

This works so long as there are no extra columns in the `current` DataFrame. However when I add an extra column:

```
>>> current
              above below cruft
asn   country
12345 MX          1     0   999
54321 MX          0     1   999
      US          1     0   999
```

I get the following:

```
>>> history = history.add(current, fill_value=0)
>>> history
               above  below cruft
asn   country              
12345 MX         7.0    3.0 999.0
      US         5.0    4.0   NaN
54321 MX         4.0    6.0 999.0
      US         1.0    0.0 999.0
```

I want this extra column to be ignored, since it's not present in both DataFrames. The desired output is just:

```
>>> history
               above  below
asn   country              
12345 MX         7.0    3.0
      US         5.0    4.0
54321 MX         4.0    6.0
      US         1.0    0.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
In [27]: history.add(current, fill_value=0)[history.columns]
Out[27]:
               above  below
asn   country
12345 MX         7.0    3.0
      US         5.0    4.0
54321 MX         4.0    6.0
      US         1.0    0.0
```

Comment: I'll be accepting this answer as I prefer the one-liner solution in this particular instance, although both answers provided so far were good and either could be preferable depending on the specific use case.

Comment: @stevendesu: could you please accept the answer if it solved your problem. its makes us easier for us to know that the question doesn't need help anymore. Thanks !

Comment: Wasn't able to accept for 10 minutes, then in those 10 minutes had a minor emergency come up :) Sorry about that

Answer (score 7):

Ummm a new way

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],join ='inner',axis=0).sum(level=[0,1])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can first specify a list of columns you need in your final output:

```
cols_to_return = ["above", "below"]
history = history[cols_to_return].add(current[cols_to_return], fill_value=0)
```

By specifying columns beforehand really helps you track what you are doing and debugging future issues.